# How can a Discord bot be made to accept commands sent by a webhook? (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, disnake

I have a python Discord bot that has several commands, and also has a webhook that sends information from a third-party service. However, the Discord bot ignores the commands entered by the webhook, without sending anything to the console. There are no attempts to access the User in the code itself (obviously there is no User). Is it possible to implement this somehow? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUb3U.png)

I tried to find information about this somewhere, but either I searched badly or there is none.

Comment: Depends on what the bot actually does after someone sends this command, if the user itself is not trivial then you can try the [on_message](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api/events.html#disnake.on_message) event this will work for messages sent with webhooks(I know cuz my voting system uses webhooks)

Answer (score -1):

webhooks are essentially a console logging of POST requests sent to discord's servers

your bot cannot receive commands sent to a webhook.